# Highcharts - Shared tooltip for categorical bubble chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, tooltip

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L284uwjc/), a shared tooltip is used. Works like a charm.

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            console.log(this);
            var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' +
                    this.y + 'm';
            });

            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    }
```

**Now I am looking for a way to show a shared tooltip for bubble charts, just like this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/gn6dtx6x/1/**

Unfortunately, the `this` object in `formatter` option property is different from the first example.

So, is there a way for shared tooltips in bubble charts, or will I have to create my own custom tooltip function?

Thank you for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate on each serie and point, comparing x value.

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>',
                x = this.point.x;
            $.each(this.series.chart.series, function (i, serie) {
                $.each(serie.data, function (j, p) {
                    if (p.x === x) {
                        s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + p.y;
                    }
                });
            });

            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gn6dtx6x/5/

Comment: Same approach as may solution, thanx still. :) Surpisingly, Highcharts changes its beaviour when it comes to shared bubble tooltips...

Comment: Yes, but I thinks that is shorter ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this with a workaround is: http://jsfiddle.net/gn6dtx6x/4/

```
tooltip: {
formatter: function () {
            return shared_tooltip (this.point.x,this.point.y);
        },
        shared: true // true|false does not matter here
    },
```

And the callback looks like this:

```
var shared_tooltip = function(x,y){

        var series = $('#container').highcharts().series;
        var s = x + '|'+y;

        $.each( series, function (key1, value1){
            var data_el_x = value1.data.filter(function(el){
                return (el.x === x);
            });
            if(data_el_x.length === 0){
                return false;
            }
            var data_el_xy = data_el_x.filter(function(el){
                return (el.y === y);
            });
            var valfreq = (data_el_xy.length === 0) ? 0 : data_el_xy[0].z;
            var allfreq = 0;
            $.each( data_el_x, function (key2, value2){
                allfreq += value2.z;
            });

            s+='<br/>'+value1.name+': '+valfreq+'/'+allfreq;

        });

        return s;

    };
```

Comment: is it possible to share tooltip between bubble and country highmap?

Comment: HI vuquanghoang, This topic is very old and little related to your question, so I suggests you to create another topic with some code and live example and also with `highcharts` tag.